# Self hosted Service is not accessible

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to write a small wcf example application with which our customer can check his network settings.
I want to have an application that self hosts a "HelloWorld" method. For that
I'm using the following code:

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:8733/Test") });
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WCFTestService.ITestService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "mex");
_serviceHost.Open();
```

When I start the application I can access the Uri with the Browser, but when I try to access the service with the client, I receive a timeout exception.

```
using (TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient())
{
    lblAnswer.Text = client.HelloWorld(txtName.Text);
    client.Close();
}
```

I think that the problem is located somewhere in how I use the client (the class is generated by the designer in the service reference), as I can access the web page of the service.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

**Additional information:**

The client is running in the same application. The customer should only copy the app to two servers, open it and type in the remote server endpoint.

**UPDATE:**
If enabled the logging for the webservice. Therefore I used this example:
[How to Enable/Disable WCF Tracing through code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anibakore/2010/11/15/how-to-enabledisable-wcf-tracing-through-code/)

The resulting log is quite long so I will only add an extract here (of what I think might be important:

- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Create ServiceHost "WCFTestService.TestService".
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Stop / ActivityName: Create ServiceHost "WCFTestService.TestService".
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Open ServiceHost "WCFTestService.TestService".
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Listen on "http://localhost:8733/Test"".
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Stop / ActivityName: Open ServiceHost "WCFTestService.TestService".
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Create channel factory. Contracttype: "WebServiceTest.ServiceReference1.ITestService"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Stop / ActivityName: Create channel factory. Contracttype: "WebServiceTest.ServiceReference1.ITestService"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Open ClientBase. Contracttype: "WebServiceTest.ServiceReference1.ITestService"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Stop / ActivityName: Open ClientBase. Contracttype: "WebServiceTest.ServiceReference1.ITestService"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Process action. "http://tempuri.org/ITestService/HelloWorld"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Information

> Extract of the data:

```
<HttpRequest>
    <Method>POST</Method>
    <QueryString/>
    <WebHeaders>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData>uIDPo02ifjHvoShOjR9brlBHbVAAAAAA/fKkCZlz30yNBa8BvF6FDOGg3TEpUTFDmlgrLzeagvkACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    </WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITestService/HelloWorld</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <name>Voß</name>
        </HelloWorld>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Received bytes on connection "http://localhost:8733/Test/"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Suspend / ActivityName: Received bytes on connection "http://localhost:8733/Test/"
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Processing message 1
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Process action "http://tempuri.org/ITestService/HelloWorld"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Transfer
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Stop / ActivityName: Processing message 1
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Resume/ ActivityName: Received bytes on connection "http://localhost:8733/Test/"
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Start / ActivityName: Process action. "http://tempuri.org/ITestService/HelloWorld"
- EventId: 0 / Type: 3 / SubType: Information

> Extract of the data:

```
<HttpRequest>
    <Method>POST</Method>
    <QueryString/>
    <WebHeaders>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData>uIDPo02ifjHvoShOjR9brlBHbVAAAAAA/fKkCZlz30yNBa8BvF6FDOGg3TEpUTFDmlgrLzeagvkACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <SOAPAction>"http://tempuri.org/ITestService/HelloWorld"</SOAPAction>
        <Connection>Keep-Alive</Connection>
        <Content-Length>164</Content-Length>
        <Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
        <Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
        <Expect>100-continue</Expect>
        <Host>localhost:8733</Host>
    </WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8733/Test/</To>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITestService/HelloWorld</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <name>Voß</name>
        </HelloWorld>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Stop / ActivityName: Received bytes on connection "http://localhost:8733/Test/"
- EventId: 131085 / Type: 3 / SubType: Error / ExceptionType: System.TimeoutException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: Have you tried switching on your logs to see what is hapening?

Comment: So is your server running on the same computer as the client?

Comment: @nvoigt: Yes and no. As I wrote it should be a test application where the app is hosting a webservice of the same type it is calling. By that I can have that app on two servers and they can call each other. But surely one could make the call with only one app running.

Comment: @mahlatse: I've added a log to the service and updated the question with the log extract.